# Balance spaces for social media lines Icons in HTML CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a social line in my website header. but the space between icon is not set.

[image]

this is the same for my three icons:

```css
.top-bar .bar-right ul.bar-social li a i {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #969696;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.list-inline-item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-left: .5rem !important;
}
```

```html
<li class="list-inline-item">
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mmaaaaaaaaaaa/">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

When I change padding-left to *25* result as:

[image]

What should I do to balance all distance between icons?

two update: this is another inspection from chrome.

[image]

[image]

Comment: use `&nbsp;` between icons

Comment: @LakshyaSrivastava you means between li :   <li  \> &nbsp; <li  \>  ?? this is not works.

Comment: can you post the snippet containing all icons

Comment: @LakshyaSrivastava please see my updates

Comment: @LakshyaSrivastava sorry but this is really a poor advice. You don't manage spaces like that, this is a bad practice.

Comment: @LaurentS. I define **li** with list-inline-item maybe the problem is that.

Comment: Please post a working snippet, I mean one that shows the error as you point it out in your screenshot. You'll notice that trying to post a good question helps you debugging. I often find the answer myself while writing the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the second part of your CSS is making it not balanced:

```
.list-inline-item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-left: .5rem !important;
}
```

This is being applied to all the items except the last one.

You probably have a much larger margin-left applied to all the items in another (maybe less specific, inherited selector) but this rule overrides it to make it smaller, but not for the last item. The last item is inheriting the larger left margin.

Try changing this to apply to all the items, if this code doesn't affect other sections of your site negatively:

```
.list-inline-item {
    margin-left: .5rem !important;
}
```

Or delete it altogether, be careful about where else this code is being  applied and possibly needed.

Using `!important` isn't appropriate in production code, it's better to use it only when debugging. It's better to understand the structure of your site and organize your code so it's as simple as it can be, to maximize maintainability.

Inspect the last item and find where the margin is being inherited from. That might give you a clue about how to structure the solution better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to using margin-right instead of padding-left

```
.top-bar .bar-right ul.bar-social li a i {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #969696;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to have a flex based wrapper:

```
.top-bar .bar-right ul.bar-social { display:flex; justify-content:center; }
.top-bar .bar-right ul.bar-social > li { flex:1; }
```

**UPDATE:** I changed the CSS-Selector so that this matches your class names

Comment: Just copy and paste it to your CSS file ;)

Comment: you means add these lines directly into css? ok?

Comment: I add these lines, nothing changed @